# Woocommerce display Reviews and Ratings by tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, review, rating-system

I am building an e-commerce website and I have installed the following plugin (Customer reviews for Commerce - https://wordpress.org/plugins/customer-reviews-woocommerce/) for Reviews and Ratings of Orders once user completes the order process.

However, the nature of the products we deal with (like fabrics, dresses, sarees etc.) will run out of stock and the same product will not be available again to procure. So, I would want to display the reviews and ratings of old orders using the 'tags' of the products which the order had (For this reason, I would like to have review at order line item). Further, the new product page should fetch the reviews and ratings using it's own tags from old orders which had the same tags.

Any guidance would be helpful in this matter!

Answer (score 1):

To approach this problem, first thing to do is to get all tags associated with a given product into an array. And then, WP_Comments_Query needs to be queried with the array of product ids generated in the first step.

Here is a snippet with the above mentioned approach.

```
function get_reviews_by_tags(){

    global $product;
    $productid = $product->get_id();
    
    // get all product_tags of the current product in an array
    $current_tags = get_the_terms( $productid, 'product_tag' );
    
    //only start if we have some tags
    if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) {
        
        //get all related product ids mapped by tags array we created earlier
        $relatedproductids_by_tags = get_posts( array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'numberposts' => -1,
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  'fields' => 'ids',
                  'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                          'field' => 'term_id',
                          'terms'     => $current_tags,
                          'operator' => 'IN'
                          )
                       ),
                   ));
       

        // create a wp comment query object as wc uses comments for reviews  
        $reviews_args = array(
                    'post__in' => $relatedproductids_by_tags
                    );
        $reviews_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
        $reviews = $reviews_query->query( $reviews_args );
    
        if ( !empty( $reviews ) ) {
            foreach ( $reviews as $review ) {
                echo '<p>' . $review->comment_content . '</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No reviews found.';
        }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'get_reviews_by_tags', 10, 2 ); 
    
}
```

The above code does not consider any modifications being made by the plugin you mentioned in your question. Also, please note that this code is for fetching and displaying reviews as mentioned in your question. This is not for creating reviews.

Comment: Thank you Naveen so much for the answer! I will try this out and mark it as accepted once the solution works for me :)